# Join 16-bit integer to make a 32-bit in Delphi?

Tags: c, delphi, integer

I would like to know what is the equivalent to Make32 function in Delphi?

See the attached image...
[image]

Comment: I think the simplest way is `i32 := i16hi shl 16 or i16lo;`.

Comment: For two words you can use MakeLong, for two bytes MakeWord.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Please post as an answer thanks!

Comment: Isn't there any way you could have posted this without a large image? It's virtually impossible to read on a mobile device, it eats data (which costs money for those using mobile devices), and the majority of the content is unavailable for those users behind a corporate proxy that blocks them. Images should only be used when they are absolutely necessary to demonstrate the problem because it can't clearly be explained in text (even if doing so means you have to put a little more effort into writing the question).

Comment: @KenWhite Because I wanted to keep the table formating (easier to read & understand) which is hard to do in text only on stackoverflow. Uploaded as a PNG (tiny size for text)

Comment: "easier to read & understand" unless you're trying to see it on a smartphone or tablet, in which case it's illegible. As I said, sometimes you need to put a little more effort into writing the question to avoid images, but when they're not absolutely necessary you should do so. *see the attached image* could have instead have been "here's an explanation of what the function does; for more details, here's a link".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `MakeLong` for two Words, and `MakeWord` for two bytes.

Answer (score 7):

I know three commonly used approaches.

**Bitwise operations**

```
u32 := (u16hi shl 16) or u16lo;
```

**`MAKELONG`**

```
u32 := MAKELONG(u16lo, u16hi);
```

**`LongRec` cast**

```
LongRec(u32).Hi := u16Hi;
LongRec(u32).Lo := u16Lo;
```